# Runs of white balls in sampling without replacement

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

There are $m$ white balls and $n$ black balls in a box. Balls are randomly drawn from the box with no return. Denote $X_1$ : number of white balls that been drawn before the first black. For $2 \leq i \leq n$, $X_i$  is the number of white balls that were pulled between the $i-1$'th and the $i$'th black balls and $X_{n+1}$ is the number of white balls pulled after the last black ball showed up.

I need to show that for all $1 \leq i,j \leq n+1: \quad X_i$  and $X_j$ have equal distributions.

I started with showing that $P(X_1 =k)=\frac{\frac{m!}{k!}n}{(n+m)!}$, and (here I'm not sure I'm right) that given $X_i=k_i$  for $i=1,2,\dots,j-1$:     $P(X_j=k_j)=\frac{\frac{(m-(k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_{j-1}))!}{k_j!} \frac{n!}{(j-1)!}}{(n-j+1+m-(k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_{j-1}))!}$ 
 Here I got stuck. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An appeal to symmetry may be easier
than a calculation. Your sample space $\Omega$ consists of all 
$m+n\choose n$ strings of $n$ black balls and $m$ white 
balls. Each such string represents the sequence of
all $m+n$ draws, and any string is equally likely to occur.

Define a map $\phi:\Omega\to\Omega$ that swaps the group
 of white balls just ahead of the $i$th black ball with 
the group of white balls just ahead of the $j$th black ball,
as in the picture below.

[image]

Now $\phi$ is a one-to-one, onto map; in fact $\phi(\phi(\omega))=\omega.$
Therefore, for any collection $B$ of sample points we have
$P(\omega:\phi(\omega)\in B)=P(\omega:\omega\in B)$, so in particular 
$X_i$ and $X_i\circ\phi$ have the same distribution.
But $X_i\circ\phi=X_j$, so we are done.

Comment: Nice +1. Hopefully OP will accept your answer and hence allow me to delete mine.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.

Comment: Very, very nice!

Comment: Sorry it took me some time to see this @Macavity but you helped a lot. Byron I'm speechless - thank you!

Comment: @UriaMor  Symmetry is a powerful idea that here allows us to 
show that $X_1,X_2,\dots, X_{n+1}$ have the same 
distribution, without knowing the distribution.

By the way, your formula for $P(X_1=k)$ is not quite correct.